# ArcGIS online Hosted Feature Service will not Open ArcGIS Desktop if only shared with a group

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, feature-service

I have an ArcGIS Online Hosted Feature Service shared with a group. When I try to open that feature service in ArcGIS desktop the feature service will not open. When I change the sharing capabilities to public the feature service will open in ArcGIS desktop. The group was created after July 2015 and I am the group administrator. Also I am signed into my ArcGIS online account when I have ArcGIS desktop open. I have also added my organizations URL in ArcGIS Administrator, and I am able to publish Feature and Map services.

Answer (score 2):

TO answer my own question after some back and forth with ESRI support we confirmed this to be a "bug" with the version of ArcGIS Desktop (10.2.2) that I was using.

From ESRI support:

> As we discussed, it looks like the issue you're seeing is only in
>   10.2.2.  Testing the same workflow where an ArcGIS Online item is shared with a group or only with the organization in 10.3 and 10.4
>   shows that the file works as expected. I've documented the behavior in
>   our system and since you will likely upgrade to a more current version
>   of the software, I will go ahead and mark this case as resolved. Feel
>   free to contact me if you have any other questions regarding this case
>   and I will be glad to re-open it if necessary.

Comment: I'm having the same problems and i'm using ArcMap 10.4.1 so i use ArcGIS Pro where it works.